# Does NPM support virtual packages? Is it possible to depend on either package A or B?

Tags: npm, dependency-management, abstraction

The Debian Package Management system has a great feature that a package can `provide` a [virtual package](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-virtual) that other packages can depend on. A great example is the [mail-transport-agent](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mail-transport-agent) package that is implemented by 25 other packages.

Now back to NPM, say, I want to reinvent the wheel by writing a [webpack loader](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html) that uses either [sass-loader](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader) or [less-loader](https://github.com/webpack/less-loader) to transform parts of my own file format into `CSS`. If I just naively go ahead, the users of my package will depend on both `sass-loader` and `less-loader` although they probably only use one of them.

I want to give the users of my loader package the choice to have either `sass-loader` or `less-loader` or both in their package, but I want to warn them if neither of them are installed. Is there a way or a workaround for this?

Comment: I have cross-posted this question to https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12553 to see if I can get faster feedback there from the community